# Notation confusion with angle brackets

Tags: notation

According to Wikipedia,

> In a plasma, particle velocity can be characterized using a probability distribution. If the plasma is thermalized, the distribution looks like a bell curve, or maxwellian distribution. In this case, it is useful to use the average particle cross section over the velocity distribution. This is entered into the volumetric fusion rate: $$P_{fusion} = n_An_B 
> \langle \sigma v_{A,B}\rangle E_{fusion}$$

Where apparently $\langle \sigma v_{A,B}\rangle$ is

> the cross section of that reaction, average over all the velocities of
>   the two species $v$

To my knowledge, anything in between angle brackets denote an inner product. What is  $\langle \sigma v_{A,B}\rangle$ expressed explicitly as given its notation?

Comment: "anything in between angle brackets is an inner product".  Not to my knowledge...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah, I see. What might it mean then?

Comment: Physicists often use $\langle X \rangle$ where mathematicians might write $E X$.

Comment: @kimchilover What does $EX$ mean?

Comment: Expectation, average value.